# How do the axioms of naturally ordered semigroup imply commutativity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Semigroup $(S,*)$ is naturally ordered (natural ordering is supposed to behave like natural numbers under addition) iff:

$1$. ${\forall}I\,{\subseteq}\,S:{\exists}m\,{\in}\,I:{\forall}n\,{\in}\,I:m\,{\preceq}\,n$

$2$. ${\forall}a,b,c\,{\in}\,S:a*b=a*c{\implies}b=c$

$3$. ${\forall}d,e\,{\in}\,S:d\,{\preceq}\,e:{\exists}f\,{\in}\,S:f*d=e$

$4$. ${\exists}p,r\,{\in}\,S:p≠r$

All naturally ordered semigroups are commutative. This apparently follows from the axioms. How?

Comment: I have a few questions. (a) Is $\preceq$ supposed to be a partial order on $S$? A partial preorder? A total order? (b) Do you assume that $(S, \preceq)$ is an ordered semigroup, that is $a \preceq b$ implies $ac \preceq bc$ and $ca \preceq cb$? (c) I assume that $I$ should be nonempty in (1). (d) What is the purpose of condition (4)? Your conditions should also work on a one-element semigroup, don't they?